# ¿Cómo instalar Hadoop en Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: hadoop

Intento utilisar multiple tutoriales. El ùltimo esta el de Michael Noll, (un enginero en Suissa)

Por lo moment tengo un problema con el estado de actualización de `$HOME/.bashrc` :
No sé de qué se trata, solo estoy siguiendo el tutorial

```
mike@mike-thinks:~$ su - hduser
Password: 
hduser@mike-thinks:~$ gedit .bashrc
No protocol specified
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:2822): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
hduser@mike-thinks:~$ gedit .bashrc
No protocol specified
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:2826): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
hduser@mike-thinks:~$ HOME/.bashrc
-su: HOME/.bashrc: No such file or directory
hduser@mike-thinks:~$ gedit HOME/.bashrc
No protocol specified
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:2833): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

Comment: El error es que no puedes abrir `gedit` el editor de texto de `gnome`, tienes instalada correctamente toda la parte gráfica y el entorno `gnome`? prueba sino editar con algún editor de consola `vi`, `nano`, etc.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho No lo sé ...

Answer (score 0):

Parece que estás intentando abrir el gedit (que es un editor de texto gráfico) desde un terminal, por lo que no puede crear la ventana.

Prueba a usar un editor de línea de comandos, como nano, en lugar de gedit.

Si sabes usar vi, también te vale

En resumen, haz:

```
nano  .bashrc
```